# Chocolatey Package Manager showing two packages for each package with (Install) in one

Tags: windows-11, chocolatey

[image]

As visible in the screenshot attached, there are two packages for some of the packages with (Install) in the package name. What does this mean and how do I remove/fix/hide the "Install" ones?

Answer (score 0):

The two packages are not identical, actually very different from each other.

The following is the answer from the post
[What's a Chocolatey "Install" package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828624/whats-a-chocolatey-install-package)

> Have a look at the FAQ in the Chocolatey wiki here:
>
> https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/faqs#what-is-the-difference-between-packages-no-suffix-as-compared-to.install.portable
>
> Quoting from that article:
>
> > tl;dr: Nearly 100% of the time, the package with no suffix (autohotkey
> > in this example) is going to ensure the *.install. The package without
> > the suffix is for both discoverability and for other packages to take
> > a dependency on.
> >
> > Chocolatey has the concept of virtual packages (coming) and meta
> > packages. Virtual packages are packages that represent other packages
> > when used as a dependency. Metapackages are packages that only exist
> > to provide a grouping of dependencies.
> >
> > A package with no suffix that is surrounded by packages with suffixes
> > is to provide a virtual package. So in the case of git, git.install,
> > and git.commandline (deprecated for .portable) – git is that virtual
> > package (currently it is really just a metapackage until the virtual
> > packages feature is complete). That means that other packages could
> > depend on it and you could have either git.install or git.portable
> > installed and you would meet the dependency of having git installed.
> > That keeps Chocolatey from trying to install something that already
> > meets the dependency requirement for a package.
> >
> > Talking specifically about the *.install package suffix – those are
> > for the packages that have a native installer that they have bundled
> > or they download and run.
> >
> > **NOTE**: the suffix *.app has been used previously to mean the same as *.install. But the *.app suffix is now deprecated and should not be
> > used for new packages.
> >
> > The *.portable packages are the packages that will usually result in
> > an executable on your path somewhere but do not get installed onto the
> > system (Add/Remove Programs). Previously the suffixes *.tool and
> > *.commandline have been used to refer to the same type of packages.
> >
> > **NOTE**: now *.tool and *.commandline are deprecated and should not be used for new packages.
> >
> > Want more information? See
> > http://ferventcoder.com/archive/2012/02/25/chocolatey---guidance-on-packaging-apps-with-both-an-install.aspx